# DIV not Scrolling correctly like Marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, marquee

As `<marquee>` tag was depreciated. I created a simple CSS to scroll my DIV from right to left.

```
<style>
 #scroll-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll-text {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  }
</style>
    
    
<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="scroll-text"> </div></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwrQBGLeIphnholKad8gvarUZ4wsMEiG9PlboMiuuB6lxW4l_UnjTuxouy2NRZkeSAd/exec"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById("scroll-text").innerHTML = marq1 + " " + "<b> <span style='color: #A000ff;'>" + marq2 + "</span> </b>" + " " + marq3 + " " + marq4 ;
</script>
```

It should scroll like marquee behaviour,

**But instead of 1 line it's scrolling by 3 lines.**

How to fix this ?

**[This is my Web Page](https://sgquizdaily.com/jsbysheets/)**

**Below is the Mobile Device Cropped Screenshot**

[image: Mobile Device Cropped Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem. Can you please add a scrrenshot? take into consideration our screens are different, therefore we might see different things if we go into the link.

Comment: I think you need to find some other solution to this. because after the animation finishes it will reset and will go back the translates 100

Comment: @YairMishnayot added mobile device screenshot.

Comment: Hi @YairMishnayot I think it's ok with desktop browser. Because I checked it by switching to `desktop site` in my mobile. But in mobile view 3 lines coming

Comment: @AliMir no problem with infinite scrolls, but problem with lines. Coming ```3 lines in Mobile```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, this should resolve the problem.

```
<style>
 #scroll-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; /*add this*/
}

#scroll-text {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: my-animation 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: It's worked very well. Thank you @manuel